# Laravel Showing my Data Arrays to index.blade.php - Undefined Offset 1

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

Im trying to show all my data in database to my index.blade.php, however, there's an error that is showing Undefined Offset 1. I used arrays. There's no data that is showing in my table form. here is my code. Please guide me im new to Laravel thanks.

> My **VIEW**
>   **Here is where the problem occurs**

```
 <div class="form-group">   
    <div class="table-responsive">  
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">  
           <tr>  
              <th>Image Name</th>
              <th>Action</th>
           </tr>  

           @foreach($promotions->$promotion)
           <tr>  
            <th>{{ $promotion->promotion_image }}</th>
            <th><a href="" class="fa fa-edit">Update</a></th>
            <th><a href="" class="">Remove</a></th>
         </tr> 
         @endforeach
        </table>  
    </div> 
</div>
```

> My **CONTROLLER** *INDEX FUNCTION*

```
public function index()
{
    $promotions = Promotion::all();
    return view('admin.airlineplus.promotions.index')->with('promotions', $promotions);
}
```

> My **CONTROLLER** *STORE FUNCTION*
>   **Here is where I store my data using arrays**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'promotion_image' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($request->has('promotion_image'))
    {   
        //Handle File Upload

        $promotion = [];
        foreach ($request->file('promotion_image') as $key => $file)
        {
            // Get FileName
            $filenameWithExt = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            //Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo( $filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            //Get just extension
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            //Filename to Store
            $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            //Upload Image
            $path = $file->storeAs('public/promotion_images',$fileNameToStore);
            array_push($promotion, $fileNameToStore);
        }

        $fileNameToStore = serialize($promotion);
    }
    else
    {
        $fileNameToStore='noimage.jpg';
    }

    foreach ($promotion as $key => $value) {
        $promotionImage = new Promotion;
        $promotionImage->promotion_image = $value;
        $promotionImage->save();
    }
    return redirect('/admin/airlineplus/promotions/create')->with('success', 'Image Inserted');
}
```

Guide me through all of this please thanks

Comment: I've got it nevermind haha. P.S Just comment below your answers ill marked them as an answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made a slight error with your foreach type changing it to this

```
<div class="form-group">   
<div class="table-responsive">  
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">  
       <tr>  
          <th>Image Name</th>
          <th>Action</th>
       </tr>  

       @foreach($promotions as $promotion)
       <tr>  
        <th>{{ $promotion->promotion_image }}</th>
        <th><a href="" class="fa fa-edit">Update</a></th>
        <th><a href="" class="">Remove</a></th>
     </tr> 
     @endforeach
    </table>  
</div>
```

`foreach` has the first option is the variable to loop through and the second is the variable for each of the loops

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: hey sir yeah I noticed that too before hehe.. I have a one more question ,,, when I updated my image .. why the image is inserted in the storage/public why it is not updated? I want to delete the previous image that has been updated... though in my case the image is inserted not updated.. but it is updated in the database any help with that?

Comment: Have a look at updateOrCreate() https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_updateOrCreate